# How to connect to a sqlite3 db file and fetch contents in fastapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I have a sqlite.db file which has 5 columns and 10million rows. I have created a api using fastapi, now in one of the api methods I want to connect to that sqlite.db file and fetch content based on certain conditions (based on the columns present). I mostly will be using SELECT and WHERE.

How can I do it by also taking advantage of async requests. I have came across Tortoise ORM but I am not sure how to properly use it to fetch results.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File, Form
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///test.db"


@app.post("/test")
async def fetch_data(id: int):
    query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID={}".format(str(id))

    # how can I fetch such query faster from 10 million records while taking advantage of async func
    return  results
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are missing a point here, defining a function with `async` is not enough. You need to use an asynchronous Database Driver to taking the advantage of using a coroutine.

[**Encode**](https://github.com/encode)'s [**Databases**](https://github.com/encode/databases) library is great for this purpose.

```py
pip install databases
```

You can also install the required database drivers with:

```py
pip install databases[sqlite]
```

In your case, this should do good.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File, Form
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from databases import Database

database = Database("sqlite:///test.db")


@app.on_event("startup")
async def database_connect():
    await database.connect()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def database_disconnect():
    await database.disconnect()


@app.post("/test")
async def fetch_data(id: int):
    query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID={}".format(str(id))
    results = await database.fetch_all(query=query)

    return  results
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Will this be fast enough when querying 10 million data? (or) Do I have to do something else?

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything else. As long as it runs as a coroutine, it will return the data without waiting for the other one to return.

Comment: But having a coroutine will not make your query execution faster but more scalable. Imagine you are sending 3 requests at the same time and each one of them returns 10 million items. They will return them without waiting for each other. So if one request returns in 1 second. 3 requests will return in 1 second too. But it will not make the 1-second query faster.

Comment: Is there a way I can access the results as dictionary, Because I want to access the respective column as `results.column1` or `results.column2` . This will be much easier, but now I have to count the columns and use `results[0] (for column 0 )`etc.,

Comment: Are you getting a list of dictionaries and you wanna get just a dictionary instead?

Comment: no I meant, is there a way to access the results using column names?

Comment: No, AFAIK even ORM's can't do that

Comment: Just one small doubts, if I have a sql server located in this ip `26.1.180.78` and port `3306` and its a mysql can you please help me how to create a connection to it and then how can I execute a insert command and commit it?

Comment: Instead of localhost use `26.1.180.78` when you are connecting to it.

Comment: Do you mean like Database(26.1.180.78)? How can I pass username, password and port info

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you, because actually my server is password protected. I have to execute and commit the results?

Comment: Yes something like this `user:pass@26.1.180.78:3306/db`, should work.

Comment: I am not being able to connect using `mysql://test:pass@26.1.180.78:3306/db`

Answer (score 0):

An approach to accessing data from a column in a query result set:

You can read a db result set into a Pandas dataframe.  From there, you can use dataframe[“column name”] to access the column data which returns a listlike iterable of that column’s data.
You can use the dataframe’s built-in to_dict() method for dictionary data.